# Summation of powers of r and reciprocal of binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, telescopic-series

Evaluate the following sum: $$\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{(m+1)(r-1)(m^{r-1})}{r\binom{m}{r}}$$

where  $\binom{m}{r}$ stands for ${}^mC_r$

> I initially tried to change this into $$\frac{m+1}{m}\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\frac{m^r}{r\binom{m}{r}}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{m+1}{m} \left(\sum_{r=1}^m \frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\frac{m^{r-1}}{\binom{m-1}{r-1}}\right)$$ to bring it into the form of $f(r)-f(r-1)$ type but this obviously got stuck, I had even tried  bringing it in the form $$\frac{m+1}{m}\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}\frac{r.m^r}{\binom{m-1}{r}}$$
> but it it got stuck again, could anyone please tell me how to proceed with my method or give me a better one? Thanks

Comment: This is a sum that the techniques of Petkovsek et al ["A = B"](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) solve (if possible). The page gives some implementations of the algorithms, they are part of most computer algebra systems by now.

Comment: Im sorry but this couldnt help me at all :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a telescoping approach.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=1}^m}&\color{blue}{\frac{(m+1)(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\binom{m}{r}}}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{(mr-m+r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\binom{m}{r}}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{(m-r+1)m^{r-1}}{r\binom{m}{r}}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{m^{r-1}}{\binom{m}{r-1}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^m\frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}\frac{m^{r}}{\binom{m}{r}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{m^m}{\binom{m}{m}}-\frac{m^0}{\binom{m}{0}}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=m^m-1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q-1}=\binom{p}{q}\frac{q}{p-q+1}$.
- In (2) we shift the index of the right hand sum to start with $0$.
- In (3) we can cancel terms since the sums telescope.

Comment: Thanks alot for this!! :D

Comment: @PoisonedVenom: You're welcome! :-)